# Whole program typing effect

Tags: python

I'm making a text adventure game in Python 3. Is there any way to add a typing effect to any text that gets printed without repeating a command after every line?

Comment: What is a "typing effect"?

Comment: OP probably means showing one character at a time, which will definitely annoy the user after 5 minutes.

Comment: If you know how to do it for a given text, write a function for it and call that function instead of calling `print`.

Comment: (I definitely remember having answered a question like this some time ago, but no idea what to search for...)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that with "typing effect" you mean that the messages should slowly appear one character at a time, you can define a function that iterates the given message and prints it one character at a time, using `time.sleep` in between to wait a bit. Make sure to `flush` the buffer after each character.

```
import time
def slow_print(msg):
    for c in msg:
        print(c, end="", flush=True)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    print()

slow_print("Hello World!")
```

If you really want to apply this for each and every output in your game (which I'd *really* not recommend) you can overwrite the `print` function, keeping a reference to the original `print` function to use within your new slow `print` function.

```
original_print = print
def slow_print(msg):
    # same as above, but using original_print instead of print
print = slow_print

print("Hello World!")
```

You could also just `def print(...)` directly, but I'd recommend defining it as a separate function and then assigning it to `print`. This way, you can still make this optional, as this will most likely annoy the player after the first few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the characters to appear as if someone were typing them so I'll just assume that

**Import modules**

```
import os
import sys
import time
from colr import color
```

**Define your function**

```
def function_name(phrase,speed,r_value,g_value,b_value):
for char in phrase:
    sys.stdout.write(color(char, fore=(r_value,g_value,b_value)))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(speed)
```

**Test the function**

```
function_name("Hello",0.05,0,255,0)
#prints the phrase "Hello" in green text
```

Alternatively you could write the function using the threading library, which would allow users to skip the typing effect if they so wish.

```
import time, threading, os, sys, tty, termios
from colr import color

def slow_type_interrupt(phrase,speed,r_value,g_value,b_value):
    done = False # this acts as the kill switch, using if statements, you can make certain button presses stop the message printing and outright display it
    def type_out():
        for char in phrase:
            if done:
                break
            sys.stdout.write(color(char,fore=(r_value,g_value,b_value)))
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(speed)
        os.system('clear')
        print(color(phrase,fore=(r_value,g_value,b_value)))

    t = threading.Thread(target=type_out)
    t.start()

    def getkey():
        ky = sys.stdin.fileno()
        Ab = termios.tcgetattr(ky)
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            key = sys.stdin.read(1)

        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(ky, termios.TCSADRAIN, Ab)
        return key

    while not done:
        key_press = getkey()
        if key_press == 'a': #You can replace a with whatever key you want to act as the "kill key"
            done = True
            os.system('clear')
            print(color(phrase,fore=(r_value,g_value,b_value)))

slow_type_interrupt("Hello this is a test. Pressing 'a' will end this and immediatley display the message",.05,0,255,0)
```

As I mentioned in the comments of the code, a can be replaced by whatever you want. The reason I use this particular method for retrieving keypresses is because it works on almost anything that runs Python. I would suggest reading up on some other ways to retrieve keyboard inputs.

Hope I could help :)